# CakePHP 3 Post Method '403 Forbidden'

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0, http-status-code-403

I came across a really strange issue today and couldn't find any solution. I am using CakePHP 3 along with MySQL and Apache. Everything was working perfect until today but when I tried to edit one of the forum post, it didn't save and I got `403 Forbidden` response. Following is the response I got:

```
Request URL:https://www.example.com/users/edit/2
Request Method: POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

The strange part is that it is working fine when I try to create new forum post as well as for `GET` request when I load the edit page. But when I modify the fields and try to save, I get stuck with `403 Forbidden`.

I tried every mean in last 6 hours but could not find any solution. I checked database user for edit permissions, tried to remove `.htaccess` file completely, cleared browser cache and cookies but nothing helped at all. The other websites in hosting account are working fine and there is no issue with them.

The only notable thing I did today is I initialized `GIT` repository and uploaded project files on git. I would really appreciate your help in solving this issue. It is really a constant headache not to be able to modify anything.

Comment: can you share your app/Config/core.php --> 'Session', also check if your session is being ended before you request that URL, are you destroying session anywhere ?

Comment: Are you including a hidden id field in your edit form? Either that or its getting blackholed by the security component.

Comment: @prats1411 I am using default php session: 'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
    ]. I am not destroying the session. It is handled with default setting.

Comment: I debugged and found that following line is throwing 403 error: if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) { ....some code... } It is not validating request as one of patch, post or put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the future reference, I solved this issue by explicitly defining request type to `POST` in `$this->Form->create` function.

It was one of the strangest error I came across while using CakePHP 3! Not sure why default `PUT` method was not working. It was converting to `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, finally i found the culprit itself by my own.. This is the explanation that i got, here you go:

If you are using csrf for security in cakephp you might found that every damn POST,GET,PUT in ajax or form will be filtered by cakephp and if not auth found cakephp will respond with 403 HTTP Status..

That mean you have to put some csrf token that like a bearer token on every your request so the cakephp recognize that request. See, if you are using AJAX call so you have to put csrf token manually explained here : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

If you created a form manually you have to put the token inside the form itself, if you creating a form using cakephp helper you will see that cakephp generated some hidden parameter like this one

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/SFW/CMS/event/comment">
  <div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" autocomplete="off" value="2a39630d2a1c20d43xxxx">
  </div>
......
```

So the option is only put those hidden field on your manually generated form.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about security you can disable the middleware check in your controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
}
```

Reference:
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/csrf.html